# running ip4 server on a Mac

Tags: go

I'm using some code from Jan Newmarch's [book on Go](http://jan.newmarch.name/go/socket/chapter-socket.html) to run a daytime server on my mac. It uses this code

```
func main() {

        service := ":1200"
        tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("ip4", service)
        checkError(err)

        listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
        checkError(err)
```

however, when I run it (on a Mac), I get this error

```
Fatal error: unknown network ip4
```

Is there anything other than ip4 that I can include in this code to avoid that error?

```
tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("ip4", service)
```

Note, I also tried `ip6` and got the same error.

Comment: what is the go version ?

Comment: @fabrizioM go version go1.3 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ResolveTCPAddr) for `ResolveTCPAddr` the only valid values for the `net` arg are "tcp", "tcp4" and "tcp6"

I suspect you're getting mixed up between `ResolveTCPAddr` and `ResolveIPAddr`

Answer (score 1):

"ip4" isn't a valid network for [ResolveTCPAddr](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ResolveTCPAddr) [(source)](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/tcpsock.go?s=1076:1131#L31).

Use [ResolveIPAddr](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ResolveIPAddr) for resolving a general IP address.

Answer (score 1):

"ip4" is not a valid string

See the Documentation for [ResolveTCPAddr](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#ResolveTCPAddr)

> ResolveTCPAddr parses addr as a TCP address of the form "host:port" or
>   "[ipv6-host%zone]:port" and resolves a pair of domain name and port
>   name on the network net, **which must be "tcp", "tcp4" or "tcp6"**. A
>   literal address or host name for IPv6 must be enclosed in square
>   brackets, as in "[::1]:80", "[ipv6-host]:http" or
>   "[ipv6-host%zone]:80".

And the code:

```
func ResolveTCPAddr(net, addr string) (*TCPAddr, error) {
        switch net {
        case "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6":
        case "": // a hint wildcard for Go 1.0 undocumented behavior
            net = "tcp"
        default:
            return nil, UnknownNetworkError(net)
        }
        a, err := resolveInternetAddr(net, addr, noDeadline)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return a.toAddr().(*TCPAddr), nil
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, there's a typo in the book